# Calling private methods by symbol name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, symbols, proc, dispatch

I have the symbol name of a method that I'd like to call with some arguments.  What I'm really trying to do boils down to this code snippet:

```
method.to_proc.call(method)
```

In this case, `method` is the symbol name of a method on the object.  In my case, I'm trying to call a method that happens to be private on the object.

This is the error output that I get:

```
>$ ruby symbol_methods.rb 
symbol_methods.rb:33:in `call': private method `test_value_1' called for "value":String (NoMethodError)
    from symbol_methods.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from symbol_methods.rb:30:in `each'
    from symbol_methods.rb:30:in `block in <main>'
    from symbol_methods.rb:29:in `each'
    from symbol_methods.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Here's a self-contained example that demonstrates this behavior:

```
data = [
  ["value", true],
  ["any value here", true],
  ["Value", true],
]

def matches_value(string)
  string == "value"
end

def contains_value(string)
  string.gsub(/.*?value.*?/, "\\1")
end

def matches_value_ignore_case(string)
  string.downcase == "value"
end

#tests
[:matches_value, :contains_value, :matches_value_ignore_case].each_with_index do |method, index|
  test = data[index]
  value = test[0]
  expected_result = test[1]
  result = method.to_proc.call(value)  # <<== HERE
  puts "#{method}: #{result == expected_result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{value}'"
end
```

The important bit is in the block marked `#tests`.  The `data` variable is a set of inputs and expected results.  The `test_value_*` methods are private methods that are the tests to run.

I've tried `public_send(method, value)` and `method.to_proc.call(value)`, but both result in the `private method` error.

What would be the right way to call a private method named as a symbol in this case?  I'm looking for both an explanation and a syntactically correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of searching, I found an alternative answer than [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send), that has an unanticipated feature benefit.  The solution is to use the [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-method) to return a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html) object for the symbol name.

A `Method` object is a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Proc.html)-like callable object, so it implements the `#call` interface, which fits the bill nicely.  [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html) has many such useful helpers defined in its interface.

In context of the original question, this is how it works:

```
#tests
[:test_value_1, :test_value_2, :test_value_3].each do |method|
  data.each do |test|
    value = test[0]
    expected_result = test[1]
    puts "#{method}: #{self.method(method).call(value) == expected_result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{value}'"
  end
end
```

The important bits are:

```
self.method(method).call(value)
```

This will convert the symbol name to a `Method` object, and then invoke the method with `value` supplied as the parameter.  This works *roughly equivalently* to the [`send` method solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37201939/6263819), in functional terms.  However, there are some differences to note.

`send` is going to be somewhat more efficient, as there's no overhead in the conversion to a `Method`.  [`Method#call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html#method-i-call) and `send` use different internal calling mechanisms, and it appears that `send` has less call overhead, as well.

The *unanticipated feature* of using `Object#method` is that the `Method` object is easily converted to a `Proc` object (using [`Method#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html#method-i-to_proc)).  As such, it can be stored and passed as a first-class object.  This means that it can be supplied in place of a block or provided as a callback, making it useful for implementing flexible dispatch solutions.

Answer (score 6):

use `send` instead.

```
puts "#{method}: #{send(method, value) == expected_result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{value}'"
```

Comment: @mudasobwa The point here is to call a private method. `public_send` is precisely what will not work.

Comment: @sawa oh, indeed, sorry for that.

Comment: @delta this is equivalent to `send(method, value == expected_result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail')`  - it should be `send(method, value) == expected_result ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'`.  Parens matter.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for the explanation.  That was quite literally the first part my question: "I'm looking for both an explanation and a syntactically correct answer."

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Thanks! I will fix it.